# retrieve the number of times that a customer have come to this store

Tags: sql

I use this SQL code to retrieve the number of times that a customer have come to this store

```html
select  
    count(time_stamp), user_id, seller_id 
from 
    user_log_format1_haminjoori 
where 
    time_stamp != 1111 
group by 
    user_id, seller_id
```

but this code calculate the same times !

For example :

```
customer1 seller1 1011  
customer1 seller1 1011
customer1 seller1 1201
```

In this example, I want show me 2 for the number of times that a customer1 have come to this store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `count(distinct)`:

```
select count(distinct time_stamp), user_id, seller_id
from user_log_format1_haminjoori
where time_stamp <> 1111
group by user_id, seller_id;
```

Comment: Wow, snazzy. Didn't know you could do this in so many different versions of SQL. +1

Comment: @EricHotinger . . . `count(distinct)` is part of the ANSI standard.  The only databases that I can think of that does not support it is MS Access.